# ASP.NET Core - How to pass a Javascript variable from View to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a variable in a Javascript function that I want to send to the controller in order to activate a specified method.

This is the code from the javascript function in the View:

```
var email = response.email;    //String with an email address

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '@Url.Action("Login", "UsersController")',
     dataType: "html",
     data: { data: email },
                                            
     success: function (data) {
         alert('Your data updated');
         return data;
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
         alert(textStatus);
     }
                                            
  });
```

This the method that I want to be activated in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(string email)
    {
        var user = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            SignIn(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View("Login", "Users");
    }
```

Everytime I run this I get the error alert, I'm pretty new to Ajax so I'm not sure how to handle it.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Give `Users` instead of `UsersController`. and dataType is not `HTML` remove that, and update the URL tp `url: '/Users/Login'` for more info see this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the controller name specified in the url in ajax needs to **remove the Controller**, that is, **change the UsersController to Users**.

And in the passed parameter data, change `{data:email} to {email:email}`, or change the Login action received parameter name from `email to data` to **ensure that the passed parameter name is consistent with the received parameter name**.

And if you want to alert the update information and then jump to the correspond view, you need to *return different information in the Login action to the success method, and then judge the data in the success method and then jump*.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Users")',
     dataType: "html",
     data: { email: email },
     success: function (data) {
         if (data == "Success") { 
           alert('Your data updated');
           window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
        } else {
           alert("Please enter correct email!");
     }
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
         alert(textStatus);
     }

  });
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(string email)
    {
        var user = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            SignIn(user);
            return Content("Success");
        }

         return Content("Wrong");
    }
```

Here is the test result:( the code in the gif is a simplified judgment.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your parameter name in the controller is named `email`, you should name the property in the object you are sending `email` too. So your ajax call should be

```js
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '@Url.Action("Login", "UsersController")',
     dataType: "html",
     data: { email: email },                          //<-- here                                            
     success: function (data) {
         alert('Your data updated');
         return data;
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
         alert(textStatus);
     }
                                            
  });
```

This will make `$.ajax()` send a string like `email=foo@bar.com` in the body of the request, that MVC can parse.